# How to convert DataGrid into DataTable in wpf?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a `Datagrid` in WPF called `Datagrid1` and it's datasource is `Dataview1`.  In the dataview I fetch 20 columns, but I only display 10 columns on `Datagrid1`.

Now I need to convert this `Datagrid1` to a `Datatable` with just the 10 columns.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be something along the lines of this. The code is to create a datatable. You would then have to edit your foreach for the logic you want to apply.

```
private void CreateDataTable()
{
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
    foreach(var item in collection)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("item.value", typeof (string));
    }        
    dt.Rows.Add("row of data");
}
```